# How to increase ulimit file limit for mac sonoma?

Tags: macos, filesystem

Here is the step I followed

Step 1: Create new file

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist
```

Step 2: paste the following content

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
        "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>limit.maxfiles</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>launchctl</string>
      <string>limit</string>
      <string>maxfiles</string>
      <string>64000</string>
      <string>524288</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ServiceIPC</key>
    <false/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Step 3:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist
```

Step 4:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist
```

Runs into

> Load failed: 5: Input/output error

I am using mac sonoma `14.3.1`

Can someone tell what am I missing here?

Comment: I tried the link, it does not work `sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 128000 524288` follow by `ulimit -n 524288 10485760` does not change `ulimit` the file allowed is still 4096